# Success message immediately- will php script execute even if the browser is closed by the user soon?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am developing a website which uses a sms API to send the same message to multiple phone numbers. I have a php script which that reads phone numbers from the DB and sends sms using the API.

Question:

Is it okay to show a success message immediately to the user upon "send"?
 -from the page itself after user types in the message and hits submit.
My understanding is that php scripts are executed in the server and only results are sent back to client. If so, messages should be sent even if the browser is closed by the user shortly after the success message is sent right?
Can i use ajax to submit the form so user is not redirected?

Comment: Yes, php script will contine execute even if you close your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using ajax
From your sms api you just use same scenario as below:

```
function function_name(){
// your sms api code goes here

if (successfully send)
return true;
else 
return false;
}



if(function_name()){
// success message
exit();
}
else {
//unsuccessful message 
exit();
}
```